# how to make redraw datatables after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a problem here, first I create data tables after I select the user using select2, so the data is dynamic according to the selected user, then next to it there is an update data button, here serves to update the data from the API if there is the latest data, for the process the data update is no problem, but there is a problem in the data tables process where after the update process, the data tables don't want to be redrawn

```
$("#name").on("change",function(){
    var cek_id = this.value;
    $("#user_id").val(cek_id);
    console.log(cek_id);
    $('#getData').DataTable().clear().destroy();
        var i = 1;
        var VendorClient = $("#getData").DataTable({
        order: [ 0, "asc" ],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        ajax: "{{route('get-user-data')}}"+"/"+cek_id,
        columns: [{
            data: null,
            render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return  meta.row+1;
            } },

        {
            data: "fullname",
            name: "fullname",
            orderable:false
        },
        {
            data: "date",
            name: "date",
            orderable:false
        }

        ]
    });
```

});

and here is the process when the data update is clicked

```
 $("#get_data").on("click",function(){
        var cek_id = $("#user_id").val();
        var  url = "{{route('get-update-data')}}"+"/"+cek_id,
        $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: url, 
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                if(data.status=='success'){
                    $('#getData').data.reload();
                }else{
                   $('#getData').data.reload();

                }
                }

            });
    });
```

I have tried various methods, including creating a globe variable for VendorClient, then after response ajax i'm adding this code  `VendorClient.ajax.reload(null, false); and get errorr (index):406 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined`
but it's not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redraw the table:

```
$('#getData').DataTable().clear().draw();
```

or

```
$('#getData').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
```

or

```
$('#getData').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(false);
```